# how can I add a dot product as a distance function in pdist of matlab

Tags: matlab

`mat_vec=zeros(100,10000);`

a dot product is `dot(xi, xj)`

```
distanceFunction = @(xi, xj)dot(xi, xj)
mat_dist=pdist(mat_vec, distanceFunction)
```

Error Infomation like

```
distanceFunction =

  function_handle with value:

    @(xi,xj)dot(xi,xj)

Error using pdist
Error evaluating distance function '@(xi,xj)dot(xi,xj)'.

Error in Task1_lab404_02 (line 45)
mat_dist=pdist(mat_vec, distanceFunction)

Caused by:
    Error using dot
    A and B must be same size.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`pdist` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) (emphasis mine):

> A distance function has the form
>
> `function D2 = distfun(ZI,ZJ)`
>
> where
>
> `ZI` is a `1`-by-`n` vector containing a single observation.
>
> `ZJ` is an `m2`-by-`n` matrix containing multiple observations. **The function must accept a matrix `ZJ` with an arbitrary number of observations**.

You can achieve that if you write the function **vectorized** over the second input. For dot product this is very easy, using either [matrix multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html):

```
distanceFunction = @(xi, xj) xj*xi';
```

or [implicit expansion](https://nhigham.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/):

```
distanceFunction = @(xi, xj) sum(conj(xi).*xj, 2);
```

Note, however, that this is **not a true distance** function, because for complex inputs `distanceFunction(a, b)` is not the same as `distanceFunction(b, a)`. Applying `pdist` will only give one of those results for each pair.

Comment: I almost linked you to your own profile, but then I remembered maths say otherwise. Close call!

Comment: @BillBokeey Hehe, I cringed a little too when typing `'` :-)

Comment: The transpose `'` is magic

Comment: @HyperGroups Just bear in mind that it's _complex-conjugate_ transpose. For simple transpose use `.'`